# How to initiate a Chromium based Vivaldi browser session using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, vivaldi

I am trying to use the [vivaldi browser](https://vivaldi.com) with Selenium. It is a chromium browser that runs very similar to chrome. I have Selenium working with Firefox (geckodriver), and Google Chrome(chromedriver), but I can't seem to find a way with Vivaldi. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the *vivaldi* binary by default is located at `C:\Users\levir\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe` you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.binary_location=r'C:\Users\levir\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

Answer (score 2):

**For future reference:**
to make Vivaldi work with selenium you need to make sure of three things :

1. The correct version of ***ChromeDriver***
2. Set selenium's driver to use Vivaldi's binary via `webdriver.ChromeOptions()`
3. Make sure you're getting the correct url (don't forget "https://")

All of the above is explained step by step with screenshots in [this blog post](https://mossab.hashnode.dev/linux-use-selenium-with-vivaldi-browser)

Comment: Thanks for the nice article. It seems that the download page does not have all versions. For example I have vivaldi snapshot version 5.3.2656.3 (100.0.4896.133), and there is no 100.0.4896.133 in [download page](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads).
See also [webdriver_manager for vivaldi](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/369) request.

Comment: As noted in download page: if you are using Chrome version 100, please download ChromeDriver 100.0.4896.60. I can use that.

Answer (score 1):

The key `executable_path` will be deprecated in the upcoming releases of Selenium.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918148/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-please-pass-in-a-servic) has the solution. I'm posting a copy of said solution with the path to Vivaldi, where the username is fetched by the script so you don't have to hard code it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import os

current_user = os.getlogin()
s = Service(rf"C:\Users\{current_user}\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("http://duckduckgo.com")  # or your website of choice
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ChromeOptions` and supply binary.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


opt = Options()
opt.binary_location = chromium_path//path to chromium binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt, executable_path="path_to_chromedriver")
```

Comment: I have this:                                                                                                                            `from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opt = Options()
opt.binary_location = (r'C:\Users\levir\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt)`                                                                 I get this error, selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.