# How to initiate AVG Secure Browser session using Selenium and Python on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, chromium

I use AVG's `Secure Browser` for searching the web. I'm wanting to write a *python* script with the `selenium` package, but I don't use Chrome, Firefox, or other popular. Is there a way of telling `selenium` which Browser I want to use by **showing it the path the Browser is located in**, on my machine?

The browser I use is currently found in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Browser\Application\AVGBrowser.exe
```

on my system. The browser acts like **Chrome** and uses the *Chrome Web Store* the download *extensions*

About the Settings:

> AVG Secure Browser is made possible by the [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) open source project and other open source software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the *AVG Secure Browser* uses the [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) engine you just need to pass the *absolute path* of the *AVG Secure Browser* binary through the `binary_location` property of `ChromeOptions` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Browser\Application\AVGBrowser.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe', options=option)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to initiate a Chromium based Vivaldi browser session using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644818/how-to-initiate-a-chromium-based-vivaldi-browser-session-using-selenium-and-pyth/59751186#59751186)
- [How to initiate Brave browser using Selenium and Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626853/how-to-initiate-brave-browser-using-selenium-and-python-on-windows/62627392#62627392)

Comment: @t0mas That seems to be a different usecase all together. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: Thanks! I've got the right browser working now. but i added the `driver.quit()` function, yet it doesn't close the window. It just gives me an error. `Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Browser\Application\AVGBrowser.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0`

Comment: [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62680396/12103053)