# Selenium Browser window not quitting

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

here is my code so far:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Browser\Application\AVGBrowser.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Browser\Application\AVGBrowser.exe', options=option)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
time.sleep(3)
driver.quit() # What im trying to fix
```

The new browser window opens but does not quit after `3` seconds. It just gives me the error:

```
C:\Users\Tomas\PycharmProjects\AutoSpotify\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Tomas/PycharmProjects/AutoSpotify/venv/Scripts/StartSpotify.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tomas/PycharmProjects/AutoSpotify/venv/Scripts/StartSpotify.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Browser\Application\AVGBrowser.exe')
  File "C:\Users\Tomas\PycharmProjects\AutoSpotify\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Tomas\PycharmProjects\AutoSpotify\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\Tomas\PycharmProjects\AutoSpotify\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Browser\Application\AVGBrowser.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Add the full stack trace of your error

Answer (score 0):

```
        Hay i just tested the code in my linux it& looks fine : 
        Try this : 
        
        # Optional argument : if not specified WebDriver will search your system PATH environment variable for locating the chromedriver
        
For windows:
        # try to place your driver within (Downloads) for example, no need to place it inside programe file or somewhere far.
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\chromedriver")
```

Answer (score -1):

You should call your `quit` in a [`finally`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) like so:

```py
...
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Browser\Application\AVGBrowser.exe', options=option)
try:
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    ...
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

This way, the `quit` function is called even if you encounter an exception while working with your `driver` object.

Comment: this still doesn't close my window, and still gives me the error???