# DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I started a selenium tutorial today and have run into this error when trying to run the code. I've tried other methods but ultimately get the same error. I'm on MacOS using VSC.

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = '/Users/blutch/Documents/Chrom Web Driver\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

I've also tried inserting C: in front of /Users. Can anyone guide me on why this is happening/how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DeprecationWarning: executable\_path has been deprecated selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717302/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-selenium-python)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This error message...

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
```

...implies that the *key* *`executable_path`* will be deprecated in the upcoming releases.

This change is inline with the **Selenium 4.0 Beta 1** [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d6acda7c0254f9681574bf4078ff2001705bf940/py/CHANGES#L101) which mentions:

> Deprecate all but `Options` and `Service` arguments in driver instantiation. (#9125,#9128)

---

### Solution

Once the *key* *`executable_path`* is deprecated you have to use an instance of the `Service()` class as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service('C:/Users/.../chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
```

---

### TL; DR

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- Bug Report: [deprecate all but Options and Service arguments in driver instantiation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/9125)
- Pull Request: [deprecate all but Options and Service arguments in driver instantiation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/9128)

Comment: How would the code setup look like then to account for this?

Comment: I get this error 
Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/Users/blutch/Documents/Python Tutorials/Selenium Tutorial.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

I'm using the code above and added driver.get(url) command. I also replaced the path with mine. I'm not sure why this is occuring

Comment: @Blutch For _`Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH`_ error, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085270/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executabl/46089751#46089751), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091420/webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path-while/50094553#50094553) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201281/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-path/49201386#49201386) discussion.