# ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host = 'api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded using GeckoDriverManager and WebdriverManager for Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, webdrivermanager-python

I made a web-scraping script using Selenium, Pandas, bf4 and GeckoDriver

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

url = "https://example/url/target"
    
option = Option()
option.headlers = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Public\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
```

With this code the script **works 100%** but as I need it to be a portable application (transfer to other computers) I don't want the user to have to manually specify the Geckodriver path, let alone have to download it.

---

Geckodriver has an auto-installer but in all the ways that I try to make i get an error, searching here in the forum I found this alternative (and the error)

```
url = "https://example/url/target"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=rGeckoDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https:www.python.org")
driver.get(url)
```

Result:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host = 'api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025186487F98>: Failed to stabilize a new connection: [Errno 11001 getaddriinfo failed',))
```

---

I also tried following the: https://pypi.org/project/geckodriver-autoinstaller/#description :

```
import geckodriver_autoinstaller
geckodriver_autoinstaller.install()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

Result:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

---

All these options I tested also with `socket.getddrinfo('localhost', 8080)` and also using Git hub personal Token in `os.environ['GH_TOKEN'] = 'exampletoken'`

Does anyone know why I'm not able to automate the driver installation?

---

W10 64 bit,
Firefox Latest Version,
Libs and anaconda latest version,
Python = 3.6,
Internet with VPN (from work)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a typo, however instead of `rGeckoDriverManager()` you should have used *`GeckoDriverManager()`* within the line:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

Effectively your code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Console Output:

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current firefox version is 97.0
Get LATEST geckodriver version for 97.0 firefox
Driver [C:\Users\debanjan.bhattacharj\.wdm\drivers\geckodriver\win64\v0.30.0\geckodriver.exe] found in cache
C:\Users\debanjan.bhattacharj\Desktop\Python Programs\Selenium3-GeckoDriverManager.py:8: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

> PS: Using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) [`executable_path` has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69918489/7429447) and you have [pass in a Service object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/7429447).