# Selenium executable_path has been deprecated

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

When running my code I get the below error string,

```
<string>:36: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
```

What could possibly be the issue? Below is the Selenium setup,

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : wd}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument("--headless")
path = (chrome)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options = options)
driver.get('https://www.1linelogin.williams.com/1Line/xhtml/login.jsf?BUID=80')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message

> DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object

means that the *key* *`executable_path`* will be deprecated in the upcoming releases.

Once the *key* *`executable_path`* is deprecated you have to use an instance of the `Service()` class as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

path = (chrome)
s = Service(path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
```

For more details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918148/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-please-pass-in-a-servic)

Answer (score 3):

DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object

In this it have to pass the service object.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service("path of execution")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

From this it will work.