# Selenium opens chrome and shows error TypeError: 'str' object is not callable using Python Classe

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-class

Im making an auth bot, but I faced with a problem! When Im trying to start my selenium bot, it opens few tabs in Chrome and do nothing. It also print that

```
"str" object is not callable
```

Can anyone solve it?

Terminal message:

```
PS E:*my path*1> & E:/Python/python.exe e:*my path*/1/main.py
e:*my path*1\main.py:32: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54545/devtools/browser/f9204f7e-ffbc-4ca1-b8f0-755537aba91f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:*my path*\1\main.py", line 76, in <module>
    bot.login()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
PS e:*my path*> [3484:9668:0113/153947.029:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [15:39:47.028] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: ╧Ёшёюхфшэхээюх ъ ёшёЄхьх єёЄЁющёЄтю эх ЁрсюЄрхЄ. (0x1F)
[3484:9668:0113/153947.029:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [15:39:47.029] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: ╧Ёшёюхфшэхээюх ъ ёшёЄхьх єёЄЁющёЄтю эх ЁрсюЄрхЄ. (0x1F)
```

P.S. I removed my *main.py* pathes in this error

My code:

```
class LoginBot():

  def __init__(self):
    #Excel reading
    wb = load_workbook('seo-fast_profiles.xlsx')
    sheet_ranges = wb['Work']
    self.login = sheet_ranges['A2'].value
    self.email = sheet_ranges['B2'].value
    self.passw = sheet_ranges['C2'].value

    #Optins and UserAgent
    user = UserAgent()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(user.random)
    self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

  def close_browser(self):
    self.browser.close()
    self.browser.quit()

  def login(self):
    browser = self.browser
    browser.get("https://seo-fast.ru/login")
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 3))
    username_input = browser.find_element(By.ID, "logusername")
    username_input.clear()
    username_input.send_keys(self.email)
    time.sleep(1)
    username_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2)
    password_input = browser.find_element(By.ID, "logpassword")
    password_input.send_keys(self.passw)
    time.sleep(5)
    password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(7)
    #cookies
    pickle.dump(browser.get_cookies(), open(f"{self.login}_cookies", "wb"))

    self.close_browser()

  def xpath_exists(self, url):
    browser = self.browser
    try:
        browser.find_element(By.XPATH, url)
        exist = True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        exist = False
    return exist

bot = LoginBot()
bot.login()
```

Snapshot of browser opened chrome by selenium:

[image: This is what selenium does]

I tried to change bot.login to something else, bit it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
PS E:*my path*1> & E:/Python/python.exe e:*my path*/1/main.py
e:*my path*1\main.py:32: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
```

...indicates that the argument [executable_path has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/7429447), instead you need to [pass in a Service object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69918489/7429447)

---

### Solution

Effectively you need to replace:

```
self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

with:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

Comment: Thanks! But now I got this error: 
`
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'start'
`

Comment: Sounds to be a different error and a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question with all the relevant details.